# Apache Flink: Streaming Window trigger, java.lang.StackOverflowException

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to use ContinuousTimeEventTrigger with timeWindow:

```scala
val timed_stamped_stream = likes_stream.map({
  p => {
    val x = p.split(",")
    (get_timestamp(x(0)), x(1).trim.toLong, x(2).trim.toLong)
  }}).assignTimestamps(new TimestampExtractor[(Long, Long, Long)] {
  override def getCurrentWatermark: Long = Long.MinValue
  override def extractWatermark(t: (Long, Long, Long), l: Long): Long = t._1
  override def extractTimestamp(t: (Long, Long, Long), l: Long): Long = t._1
}).keyBy(2).timeWindow(Time.of(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))


timed_stamped_stream.trigger(ContinuousEventTimeTrigger.of(Time.of(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))).sum(1).print()
```

But I am getting a java.lang.StackOverflowError while executing it on flink streaming cluster with following stackTrace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:628)
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$Context.registerEventTimeTimer(WindowOperator.java:532)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.ContinuousEventTimeTrigger.onEventTime(ContinuousEventTimeTrigger.java:61)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$Context.onEventTime(WindowOperator.java:558)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$Context.onEventTime(WindowOperator.java:562)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$Context.onEventTime(WindowOperator.java:562)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$Context.onEventTime(WindowOperator.java:562)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$Context.onEventTime(WindowOperator.java:562)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$Context.onEventTime(WindowOperator.java:562)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$Context.onEventTime(WindowOperator.java:562)
```

Anyone there who can help?

Comment: Why are you trying to use the ContinuousEventTimeTrigger? In your case you should just have to specify timeWindow(...) and this will have an appropriate default trigger.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem but I wasn't successful. Could you maybe post example input data which reproduces the problem. Which version of Flink are you using?

Comment: What I am trying to do is something like this:
There is a stream of tuples coming as a filestream. Each of these tuple has a timestamp attached to it. I want to batch the tuples within 5 second interval. Each of these batches have to be processed periodically at an interval of 5 seconds.

Comment: I am using Flink 0.10.1

Comment: On thing I see is that you are generating a watermark for every element, which may cause very many event time triggers to be concurrently evaluated. Try to replace your own 'TimestampExtractor' with an 'AscendingTimestampExtractor'.

Comment: Thanks. Can someone send me a link to stream processing example that uses Continuous time triggers?